# HTML HREF Relative Path resolving differently for different users

Tags: html

I'm having a bizarre problem...

I have an internal endpoint that returns a simple webpage with links to endpoints with a relative path...

https://URL/APP/Api/Describe which returns the below html

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Object List</h1>
<li><a href='./Describe/thing'>thing</a></li>
...
</body>
</html>
```

For MOST users the link renders correctly as (and displays the correct result)
https://URL/APP/Api/Describe/thing

BUT for other users we get:
https://URL/APP/Api/Describe/Describe/thing
which naturally errors out.

This happens in Chrome and IE...
(Windows Server 2016, IIS 10+)

Whyfor it do dat? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are some users using https://url/APP/Api/Describe and others https://url/APP/Api/Describe/ with a trailing slash?

Comment: Yikes... They were clicking on a link I provided in email... But I guess the browser might be auto-completing a trailing slash. Is there a way to clean that from the server end?

Comment: Aha... The email link was tacking on a slash when clicked... (But not for everyone... - likely some M$ "feature" ). I should be able to account for either though...

Comment: Apparently I missed this lesson in Webserver 101 class... Anyway... I'm now reading the original URI string and generating content based on the presence or absence of the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
        string z_prefix = "./Describe/";
        char[] z_search = { '/', '\\' };
        if (Url.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.LastIndexOfAny(z_search) == Url.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.Length - 1)
        {
            z_prefix = "./";
        }
```